# BotFramework-WebChat v4: post activity to direct line from the UI to the bot

Tags: react-native, botframework, web-chat

My WebChat code is based on the React [minimizable-web-chat](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/06.recomposing-ui/a.minimizable-web-chat) v4.

I want to send a message to the bot when user click the location button.

**handleLocationButtonClick** function is called and it sends latitude and longitude to the bot.

This is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStore, createStyleSet } from 'botframework-webchat';

import WebChat from './WebChat';
import './fabric-icons-inline.css';
import './MinimizableWebChat.css';

export default class extends React.Component{

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleFetchToken = this.handleFetchToken.bind(this);
    this.handleMaximizeButtonClick = this.handleMaximizeButtonClick.bind(this);
    this.handleMinimizeButtonClick = this.handleMinimizeButtonClick.bind(this);
    this.handleSwitchButtonClick = this.handleSwitchButtonClick.bind(this);
    this.handleLocationButtonClick = this.handleLocationButtonClick.bind(this);

    const store = createStore({}, ({ dispatch }) => next => action => {
      if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED') {
        dispatch({
          type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
          payload: {
            name: 'webchat/join',
          }
        });
      }
      else if(action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/INCOMING_ACTIVITY'){
        if (action.payload.activity.name === 'locationRequest') {
          this.setState(() => ({
            locationRequested: true
          }));
        }
      }
      return next(action);
    });

    this.state = {
      minimized: true,
      newMessage: false,
      locationRequested:false,
      side: 'right',
      store,
      styleSet: createStyleSet({
        backgroundColor: 'Transparent'
      }),
      token: 'token'
    };
  }

  async handleFetchToken() {
    if (!this.state.token) {
      const res = await fetch('https://webchat-mockbot.azurewebsites.net/directline/token', { method: 'POST' });
      const { token } = await res.json();

      this.setState(() => ({ token }));
    }
  }

  handleMaximizeButtonClick() {
    this.setState(() => ({
      minimized: false,
      newMessage: false
    }));
  }

  handleMinimizeButtonClick() {
    this.setState(() => ({
      minimized: true,
      newMessage: false
    }));
  }

  handleSwitchButtonClick() {
    this.setState(({ side }) => ({
      side: side === 'left' ? 'right' : 'left'
    }));
  }

  handleLocationButtonClick(){
    var x = document.getElementById("display");
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);

      this.setState(() => ({
        locationRequested: false
      }));

    }
    else 
    {
      x.innerHTML = "Geolocation API is not supported by this browser.";
    }

    function showPosition(position) {
        x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;

        this.store.dispatch({
          type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_MESSAGE',
          payload: { text: 'latitude:'+position.coords.latitude+'longitude:'+position.coords.longitude }
        });
    }
  }

render() {
    const { state: {
      minimized,
      newMessage,
      locationRequested,
      side,
      store,
      styleSet,
      token
    } } = this;

    return (
      <div className="minimizable-web-chat">
        {
          minimized ?
            <button
              className="maximize"
              onClick={ this.handleMaximizeButtonClick }
            >
              <span className={ token ? 'ms-Icon ms-Icon--MessageFill' : 'ms-Icon ms-Icon--Message' } />
              {
                newMessage &&
                  <span className="ms-Icon ms-Icon--CircleShapeSolid red-dot" />
              }
            </button>
          :
            <div
              className={ side === 'left' ? 'chat-box left' : 'chat-box right' }
            >
              <header>
                <div className="filler" />
                <button
                  className="switch"
                  onClick={ this.handleSwitchButtonClick }
                >
                  <span className="ms-Icon ms-Icon--Switch" />
                </button>
                <button
                  className="minimize"
                  onClick={ this.handleMinimizeButtonClick }
                >
                  <span className="ms-Icon ms-Icon--ChromeMinimize" />
                </button>
              </header>
              <WebChat
                className="react-web-chat"
                onFetchToken={ this.handleFetchToken }
                store={ store }
                styleSet={ styleSet }
                token={ token }
              />
              {
                locationRequested ?
                <div>
                  <p id="display"></p>
                  <button onClick={this.handleLocationButtonClick}>
                    Gélolocation
                  </button>
                </div>
              :
              <div></div>
              }
            </div>
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

When I click the button, I have this error:

[image]

And in the console:

[image: ![enter image description here]

What is wrong ??

Comment: use `this.state.store.dispatch({ ...})`

Answer (score 0):

First, there have been some updates to the [a.minimizable-web-chat](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/samples/06.recomposing-ui/a.minimizable-web-chat/src/MinimizableWebChat.js#L10) sample that are worth looking over. Refer to the code, however, as the README.md file has not been fully updated to reflect the changes.

As for your question, try the following changes. When tested, it works successfully for me. Change the component to a function and define `store` via `useMem0()`.

```js
import React, { useCallback, useMemo, useState } from 'react';

const MinimizableWebChat = () => {
  const store = useMemo(
    () =>
      createStore({}, ({ dispatch }) => next => action => {
        if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED') {
          dispatch({
            type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
            payload: {
              name: 'webchat/join',
              value: {
                language: window.navigator.language
              }
            }
          });
        } else if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/INCOMING_ACTIVITY') {
          if (action.payload.activity.from.role === 'bot') {
            setNewMessage(true);
          }
        }

        return next(action);
      }),
    []
  );

  [...]

  return (
    [...]
    <WebChat
      [...]
      store={store}
  );
}

export default MinimizableWebChat;
```

Given the changes implemented in this file, it *likely* will impact how the other files function with it. My recommendation would be to do a wholesale update to bring your project in line with the current sample. It's really just this file, `WebChat.js`, and possibly `App.js`. There are supporting CSS files and the like that can be downloaded, if you don't have them.

Hope of help!